# A line passing through 2 semicircles inside a semicircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

[image: The diagram for the question]

(Assume that the black line is tangent to the small circle passing through the point of contact of the 2 inner semicircles.)

This was forwarded to me by maths teacher. I tried solving the problem by using coordinates but did not succeed. Is it even possible to solve this using coordinates?

Also is there a geometrical way to solve this? I tried different things by using properties of tangents and angles in a semicircle. But again, I was not able proceed in the direction of the solution.

PS : @Blue has also discussed the otheer cases in the comments section, but the main assumption is the correct one as @Yves has pointed out in his answer.

Comment: Is a black line a tangent to the little circle?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, a tangent from the endpoint of the inner semicircle. Extending that we get our division in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Would it be a biased assumption to say that the black line crosses the two semicircles where they are tangent to each other?

Comment: Mh, that line could be defined as tangent to the small circle and through one of the points $c$ or $t_1$ or $t_2$, which are the top corner and the tangency points of two circles ($t_2$ unlikely). It could also be the line through two of these points. I see five options (maybe some are identical), we need an absolute confirmation.

Comment: The condition the line passes through the contact point of the two magenta? semicircles is enough to deduce $\frac{x}{y} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @achillehui I also believe thats the only condition we should assume as now I can see that the black line can't really be tangent to the small circle. As the point where the black line appears to be tangent to the circle, is also where it is mutually tangent to the semicircle, and our black line obviously does'nt seem tangential to both of them. Michael Rozenberg, Looking more carefully, I have changed my assumption.

Comment: @achillehui Can you post your solution?

Comment: I concur with @achillehui. If the line passes through the contact point of the semicircles, then $x/y=\sqrt{2}$. This makes the small circle irrelevant. If the small circle isn't supposed to be irrelevant ... According to my GeoGebra sketch, the line through the end of the semicircle, and *tangent* to the small circle, gives $x/y=1.746\ldots$; the line through the end of the semicircle through the point of tangency of the small circle and other semicircle gives $x/y=1.850\ldots$; if there's some other relationship with the small circle, the figure doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @Blue I think that the small circle does'nt become irrelevant as it defines a unique position of the 2 semicircles(?)

Comment: @RaahilRai: Hmmmm ... Suppose that the center of the enclosing semicircle is $(0,0)$, and that its radius is $r$, and that the point of contact of the semicircles is $(0,s)$. Then the smaller semicircles have radius $s$, so that the center of, say, the right-hand one is $(s,s)$. For only a certain value of $s$ relative to $r$ does a circle of radius $s$ about $(s,s)$ meet the enclosing semicircle at diametric points. This alone is enough to define the unique positions of the inner semicircles, isn't it?

Comment: @Blue I believe it is. The small circle just makes the problem look more visually-appealing and can also geometrically set the arrangement of the inner semicircles. Btw, can you share your GeoGebra file or you can give your solution and attach it over there. Also, now Yves's answer tells us that 2√2 -1 ≈ 1.82 is also a possibilty. Can you confirm that with your GeoGebra sketch?

Comment: @RaahilRai: My GeoGebra sketch isn't in any condition to share. :)  And I don't really want to go chasing-down what "might" be an answer. Please simply update the question when you confirm with your instructor what the proper conditions are.

Comment: Black can not be tangent to smaller circle since it would be also for right semicircle  but that is not the case since it cutsit in two points already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the radius of a large half-circle to be $4$, in the triangle formed by its center, its contact point with the axis of symmetry and the center of the small circle, of radius $r$, we have by Pythagoras

$$(4-r)^2+4^2=(4+r)^2$$ and $r=1$.

Now in the triangle formed by the contact point of the large half-circle, the center of the small and the tangency point of the line, the hypothenuses is $3$ and a side is $1$, hence the other side $\sqrt8$. By similarity,

$$\frac y4=\frac1{\sqrt8}$$ while $$x=4-y.$$

[image]

> $$\frac xy=\sqrt8-1.$$

---

This solution assumes that the line is the tangent to the small circle by the point of contact of the two large ones.

---

**Update:**

If we instead assume the line to be through the tangency point of the large and small circle, by similarity of the triangle $3-4-5$, we know the position of this tangency point, and again by similarity

$$\frac y4=\frac{\frac45}{3-\frac35},$$

[image]

giving

> $$\frac xy=2.$$

Comment: Doesn't that give an answer of $2\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: @Plato: yes, it does.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll make the construction to see if your assumption is true. Otherwise you'd have another hurdle to overcome.

Comment: @Plato: by direct measurement on the drawing, the ratio is approximately $1.83$, closer to $1.8284$ than $1.4142$.

Comment: That's actually true. Maybe the OP got half a hint

Comment: @Plato That can definitely be a possibilty. But if I want the answer to be $\sqrt2$, then how should one proceed with the solution because as Blue pointed out in the comments, if we assume the line passing through the point of contact of the semicircles then we'll get the answer as $\sqrt2$. Yves, Plato any ideas?

Comment: @RaahilRai: I doubt that the answer can be $\sqrt2$, much too far from the measured $1.83$ and I will not try. By the way, nobody *proved* this $\sqrt2$. In any case, the ratio of the circle radii is guaranteed to be $4$.

Comment: Black can not be tangent to smaller circle since it would be also for right semicircle  but that is not the case since it cutsit in two points already.

Comment: @Aqua: you are assuming that the black line is through the tangency points of two circles, but this was not confirmed. I clearly stated my assumption.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I completely agree with you and I have edited my question accordingly too. Thanks for your clarification and efforts!

Comment: @ Raahil Rai Honestly, the only thing I confirmed with certainty is that $x+y$ is equal to the radius of one of the semicircles

Comment: @RaahilRai: I added another solution, which is also likely.